# How can I convert a deep nested array into a deep nested object, using recursion?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will convert an array like this:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', [['d', 4]]]]
```

Into an object like this:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 4 } }
```

So far I just have a function that converts a regular array to regular object, and I'm getting the hang of recursion I'm just not sure how to implement it in such a case. Here is the function that I am working with:

```
const deepArrayToObject = function(arr) {
  let obj = {};
  if (arr !== []) {
    return obj;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      let key = arr[i][0];
      let value = arr[i][1];
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I just noticed that you have some arrays "double wrapped", like this: `[['d', 4]]`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

The trick would be to check whether the `value` of a given property is an `array`. If it is, call the function again on the `value`, otherwise use the `value` as is.

Here's a version using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const a = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', [['d', 4]]]];

const o = arrayToObject(a);
console.log(o);

function arrayToObject(a) {
  return a.reduce((o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, {
   [k]: Array.isArray(v) ? arrayToObject(v) : v,
  }), {});
}
```

The [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function  allows you to append the properties of one or more objects onto a target object.

In the example below, the properties of object `b` will be appended to object `a` and `a` returned. Therefore `a` and `c` are the same object.

```js
const a = { a: 'A' };
const b = { b: 'B' };
const c = Object.assign(a, b);

console.log(a, c, a === c);
```

The ternary operator is a short-hand `if` statement. In the function it is checking if `v` is an array. If it is, the array value is passed to the function again initiating the recursive call.

It could be rewritten:

```
if (Array.isArray(v)) {
    return arrayToObject(v);
} else {
    return v;
}
```

Comment: A minor note - here a new object is created at each iteration of `reduce`. More efficient approach would be to modify it in place. `(o, [k, v]_ => { o[k] = ...; return o; }`

Comment: `Object.assign` does actually return the target object specified as the first parameter, so it is modifying the existing object rather than creating a new object each time. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more information. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/pavisotiqe/edit?js,console) showing this.

Comment: No worries. I did have to double check to make sure :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion, works great! I had a feeling I might have needed the Array.isarray. Can you break down the use of object.assign for me with the use of the ternary operator? I think I get it but it would be nice to have a deeper understanding of it (have also checked MDN on it as it is relatively new to me). Thanks again.

Comment: I've added an extended explanation. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You need only one loop, and for the `value`, check to see which you have, and if it's an array, do the recursion.

```js
const deepArrayToObject = function(arr) {
  let obj = {};

  // This does nothing useful
  //  if (arr !== []) {
  //    return obj;
  //  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let key = arr[i][0];
    let value = arr[i][1];
    
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      obj[key] = deepArrayToObject(value);
    } else {
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

const a = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', [['d', 4]]]];

const res = deepArrayToObject(a);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks slappy! works perfect and easy for my beginner mind to grasp :). I had a feeling I was just a few small steps away. I forgot to remove that conditional that you commented out as I just started working on it after a break and added that as a start, then thought that wasn't the right way, I should get some help! thanks again.